# QObject class in nested namespace

Tags: qt

After i moved `QObject` classes in nested namespaces, method `moveToThread` started giving me error:

> cannot initialize object parameter of type 'QObject' with an
>   expression of type 'Parsers::Downloaders::YouTube'

From this error I figured out that I can't make `QObject` class in nested namespace.
Header file for `Parsers::Downloaders::YouTube` class:

```
namespace Parsers::Downloaders
{
    class YouTube : public Parsers::DownloaderClass
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        // some stuf here
    };
}
```

`DownloaderClass` derived from `QObject` class. Can I in some way have `QObject` derived class in nested namespace?

Example:

```
QThread *thread = new QThread();
Parsers::Downloaders::YouTube *api = new Parsers::Downloaders::YouTube();
api->moveToThread(thread);
```

I use Qt 5.14.1.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Is `namespace Parsers::Downloaders` a valid C++ syntax? You should write it rather as `namespace Parsers { namespace Downloaders {...} }`.

Comment: You can not use nested classes in Qt

Comment: @vahancho It’s valid since C++17. It might confuse moc though… Ullov, can you paste more context of the error message (which file, for example), and which Qt version do you use?